# Prevent redirect to next page after submit

Tags: php, database, email, redirect

I got a contact form which will send an email and write to a database. The problem is it will redirect to a new page.

index.php jQuery code:

```
            $( "#sendform" ).submit(function(e) {

            //e.preventDefault();
            //alert( "Handler for .submit() called." );
        });
```

detail.php form:

```
<form name="contactform" id="sendform" method="POST" action="<?php echo $editFormAction;?>">
<div id="links">

<h2>Uw Boodschap</h2>
<textarea name="message"></textarea>

</div>
<div id="rechts">
    <img src="" id="postzegel" name="postzegel" width="80" height="64" class="kaart"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="kaartURL" id="kaartURL" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="kaartNr" id="kaartNr" value="<?php echo $kaartNr?>"/>
    <h2 class="afzender">Afzender</h2>
    <input type="text" value="Uw naam" name="naamzender" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Uw naam') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Uw naam';}" maxlength="50" size="33">
    <input type="text" value="Uw Email" name="emailzender" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Uw Email') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Uw Email';}" maxlength="50" size="33">
            <h2>Ontvanger</h2>
    <input type="text" value="Naam" name="naamontvanger" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Naam') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Naam';}" maxlength="50" size="33">
    <input type="text" value="Email"name="emailontvanger" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Email') {this.value = '';}"  onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Email';}"maxlength="50" size="33">
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Verzend mijn Ecard" >

</div>
<input type="hidden" name="MM_insert" value="contactform" />
</form>
```

I have set this variable `$editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];`
and I have the redirection set to

```
$insertGoTo = "index.php"; if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) { $insertGoTo .= (strpos($insertGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?"; $insertGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']; } header(sprintf("Location: %s", $insertGoTo));
```

If I leave out the redirection it will just redirect to detail.php after submit and if I use `e.preventDefault` it wont execute the email/database php code. I want to execute the email/database php code without changing or reloading the page.

Comment: You seem to be creating an infinite loop of submitting the form with that jQuery code. preventDefault will stop the form from redirecting/processing (why is this commented out if thats what you want to do?), however you will need to capture the data and submit it in another way (e.g. an ajax call).

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to remove that line

Comment: Try using [**ajaxSubmit**](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) This traps the response of form submission and provides a handler to take custom action on submit.

Comment: Can I execute the database/email php code inside jquery?

Comment: Thats the problem. I dont realy know how to capture that data from the phpemail/database.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will work

```
  $("#sendform").on('submit', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log($(this).attr('action'));
      console.log($(this).serialize());
      $.ajax({
         url: $(this).attr('action'),
         data: $(this).serialize()
     }).done(function (data) {
        if (console && console.log) {
          console.log("form submitted Nice Aaah");
        }
     });
   });
```

Comment: I used this code and nothing happened. Please note I wrote my entire database/email php code inside detail.php which will be executed after i press submit.

Comment: cant you separate that code to another file(don't include  email.php into details.php'). if you do that it will be more modular . so details.php will have the form, and action would be database/email.php ,then it will work , and in email.php , you need to unserialize the $_REQUEST then you will get the array of form variables (use parse_str($str))

Comment: I just added the entire email and database php code into database.php and wrote my form action as: action="database.php". Ofcourse it will make me redirect to database.php which should be prevented.. only the php code should be executed

Comment: can you check the form id , are you using sendform as id for your form ?,if it is the same it should work. look at here http://jsfiddle.net/SHYp5/,